# Any Plugin For In app display calendar Cordova

Tags: cordova, calendar, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I would like to ask any cordova/phonegap plugin that can display a calendar inside my application, where user allow click on certain date perform action.

Thanks.

Example : ScreenShot From An Application
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=480297695450952&set=a.265532286927495.1073741826.100004121760330&type=1&theater

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Calendar directly into your app.
You will need iframe for google calendar which can be opened using in-app browser in Cordova.

You can even use Phonegap calendar plugin : https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=480297695450952&set=a.265532286927495.1073741826.100004121760330&type=1&theater ,for example I saw a application got implement this calendar, and i wondering any plugin allow me to do like that. Thanks